# <object>-Element is not expanding to the size of it's inner content

Tags: html, css

I use an `<object>` Element to load an `<svg>` element in a HTML file. My problem is, that the `<object>` does not expand to the size of it's inner content, like I want it to.

[Screenshot of a website where this problem occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIgK0.png)

On the screenshot you should (when it works), be able to see a whole map of Germany. The problem is, I can't set fixed values for with and height, because other country-maps have other sizes, so it must me dynamic.

Another thing later on is, that I want to be able to scale the whole `<object>` element, is this possible?

My code looks like the following:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/misc/apps/select/state/' . $_GET['country'] . '.svg"></object>
```

But you can see the example yourself by calling this link:
(Country accepts countries within the European Union)

https://languently.net/select/state?country=DE

I'm pretty sure, the `<svg>` tag does not expand correctly, because the `<g>` inside has the right size. That's all I found out while troubleshooting with a friend of mine.

Comment: Please provide an  minimal reproducible example using the snippet functionality. It helps us to help you. We can't blindly guess your html and css structure. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

try setting width and height for object element by value 100%

Comment: If I do this, the `<svg>` within also expands to the full size of the `<object>` while I just want it to be as large as it has to go to make all `<g>` tags visible.. I've done this under my posted link, may you see this, when you call it, the blue area is far to large